# What's wrong with this Jquery script?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Trying to populate a drop down list for cities once a user makes a selection for the state using Jquery/Ajax functionality

HTML Form has...

```
  <?php $allRegions = Region::newInstance()->getStatesByCountry('US'); ?>



     <select name="regionId" id="regionId">

     <?php foreach($allRegions as $region) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $region['value'] ; ?>"><?php echo $region['name'] ; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
     </select> 

       <select name="cityId" id="cityId">Choose a city</select>
```

Jquery code...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){



  $("#regionId").change( function() {

  var regionId = $(this).val();

  var url = '<?php echo site_base_url(true)."?page=ajax&action=cities&regionId="; ?>' + regionId;

  $.ajax({
  type: "GET"
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(msg){
  if (msg != ”){
  $("#cityId").html(msg).show();

  }

  }
  });
  });
  });
  </script>
```

The issue is that on selecting a region the cities drop down select doesn't get populated ... can't figure it out.. any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error are you experiencing?

Comment: What is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Copying code from internet pages... make sure to get rid of the *secure formatting* they use.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - What's that and how do we get rid of it ?

Comment: Try to use in-browser developer console to see exact javascript errors occuring on your page.

Comment: Ever heard about indenting code? You are the one who requires help - you should at least take the time and effort to ask a clean, easily readable question. -1 from me. Any error messages in the console? Is the jQuery code output from a PHP file (because you seem to use PHP code in there)?

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that you have a strange quote character:

```
if (msg != ”){
```

You probably mean this:

```
if (msg != ''){
```

Comment: Fixed that and the other one as well as pointed by @Raminson but still deosn't work...

Comment: not exactly sure how to use  but i See nothing in firebug ... not in console option for firebug as well ... and no errors in console as well.. i'm realy not sure if any error messages are or can be supressed... i'm  modifying code written by another developer...

Comment: Also, the text ' choose a city ' doesn't appear in the cities dropdown box although the dropdown itself is there...

Answer (score 2):

and another problem is:

```
  type: "GET"
```

that should be:

```
  type: "GET",
```

Comment: Fixed that and the other one as well as pointed by @Mark but still deosn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Not to be rude, but your code is very nested, and unecessary complicated.
Fix all the mentions above from the others, and also this:

```
 <?PHP
 foreach($allRegions as $region) {
 <option value="<?php echo $region['value'];" . "><" . echo $region['name']; .
 "</option>" } ?>
 </select>
```